# Generate NPM package using open-api-generator gradle plugin

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

Is it possible to generate npm package using the open api generator plugin for gradle?

I am generating the .ts model classes and I saw that the typescript-angular generator has some properties like npmName, npmVersion and so on and this made me think that it would be possible to create also the npm package with the plugin.

So far I didn't manage to generate it or to find an exmaple somewhere.

This is an example of the configuration that I tried

```
task buildTypeScriptClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
        generatorName = "typescript-angular"
        inputSpec = "$rootDir/${project.name}/api-definition/${apiDefinitionFile}".toString()
        outputDir = "$buildDir".toString()
        validateSpec = false
        modelPackage = "model.${project.name}-service-client"

        configOptions = [
                ngVersion    : "8.0.0",
                npmName      : "some-typescript-client",
                npmVersion   : "1.0.0",
                npmRepository: "some repo",
                snapshot     : "false",
                supportsES6  : "true"
        ]

        systemProperties = [
                models: "" //generates all model classes
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this is the configuration that I used:

```
task buildTypeScriptClient(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
        generatorName = "typescript-angular"
        inputSpec = "$rootDir/${project.name}/api-definition/${apiDefinitionFile}".toString()
        outputDir = "$buildDir".toString()
        validateSpec = Boolean.valueOf(project.validateOpenApiFile)
        supportingFilesConstrainedTo = ["package.json"]
        modelPackage = "${project.name}-client/model"
        templateDir = "$rootDir/${project.name}/template/"

        configOptions = [
                ngVersion    : "8.0.0",
                npmName      : "${project.name}-client",
                npmVersion   : "${project.version}",
                npmRepository: project.NEXUS_UPLOAD_URL
        ]

        additionalProperties = [
                backendService: "${project.name}".toString()
        ]

        systemProperties = [
                models    : "",
                modelDocs : "false",
                modelTests: "false",
                apis      : "false"
        ]
    }
```

I am using a package.mustache template for the generation of a custom package.json in this form:

```
{
    "name": "{{npmName}}",
    "version": "{{npmVersion}}",
    "description": "This package contains the DTO classes (generated by open api generator) used for the REST interface of {{backendService}}",
    "private": false,
    "license": "unlicensed",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://git-repo.com/{{backendService}}"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "package": "npm pack"
    },
    "files": [
        "{{modelPackage}}/*"
    ]
}
```

I am also using a custom npm gradle plugin, build on top of the com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.3.1, with which I package the client in a zip file and publish it to the remote repository.